# Kivy sdl2 - RuntimeError: b'Could not initialize EGL

Tags: python, kivy

I try to run the following sample script on Windows 7 with OpenGL 1.1:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label

class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return Label(text='Hello world')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

and i receive the following error

```
[INFO ] [Logger ] Record log in C:\Users\Admin.kivy\logs\kivy_20-03-09_20.txt 
[INFO ] [deps ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.gstreamer" 0.2.0 
[INFO ] [deps ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.angle" 0.2.0 
[INFO ] [deps ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.glew" 0.2.0 
[INFO ] [deps ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.sdl2" 0.2.0 
[INFO ] [Kivy ] v1.11.1 
[INFO ] [Kivy ] Installed at "F:\Data_analytics\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy_init_.py" 
[INFO ] [Python ] v3.6.0 (default, Jan 23 2017, 17:35:20) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] 
[INFO ] [Python ] Interpreter at "F:\Data_analytics\venv\Scripts\python.exe" 
[INFO ] [Factory ] 184 symbols loaded 
[INFO ] [Image ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_gif (img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored) [INFO ] [Text ] Provider: sdl2 
[INFO ] [Window ] Provider: sdl2 
[INFO ] [Window ] Activate GLES2/ANGLE context 
[CRITICAL] [Window ] Unable to find any valuable Window provider. Please enable debug logging (e.g. add -d if running from the command line, or change the log level in the config) and re-run your app to identify potential causes sdl2 - RuntimeError: b'Could not initialize EGL' File "F:\Data_analytics\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\core_init_.py", line 71, in core_select_lib cls = cls() File "F:\Data_analytics\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 152, in init super(WindowSDL, self).init() File "F:\Data_analytics\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window_init_.py", line 981, in init self.create_window() File "F:\Data_analytics\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 290, in create_window self.get_gl_backend_name()) File "kivy\core\window_window_sdl2.pyx", line 224, in kivy.core.window._window_sdl2._WindowSDL2Storage.setup_window File "kivy\core\window_window_sdl2.pyx", line 74, in kivy.core.window._window_sdl2._WindowSDL2Storage.die

[CRITICAL] [App ] Unable to get a Window, abort.
```

I have used user environment variable KIVY_GL_BACKEND with value angel_sdl2.

Any idea what should i correct and get a successful result?

Answer (score 2):

Try doing this if you installed kivy with pip

---

```
python -m pip uninstall kivy
python -m pip uninstall kivy.deps.sdl2
python -m pip uninstall kivy.deps.glew
python -m pip uninstall kivy.deps.gstreamer
```

Now reinstalling everything except gstreamer.

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip wheel setuptools
python -m pip install docutils pygments pypiwin32 kivy.deps.sdl2 
kivy.deps.glew --extra-index-url https://kivy.org/downloads/packages/simple/
python -m pip install kivy
```

Got this from https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/6071

You could use conda instead after installation step(I personally prefer this).

```
conda install -c evindunn pygame
conda install -c conda-forge kivy
```

Comment: Unfortunately OpenGL 2+ is required to be installed in order to work properly. Otherwise I don't know any other way to work with Kivy framework successfully.                                          Regards

Comment: Are you having trouble updating to  OpengGL 2+ on Windows??

Comment: At the moment I have got a graphics card that is old enough to support OpenGL 2+ via drivers update. Do you know any other way to update my OpenGL engine from 1.1 to 2+ ? That would help me a lot! Regards

Comment: check this out https://superuser.com/questions/458629/updating-opengl-to-2-0

Comment: Thanks for your assistance! Unfortunately i can not find any recent update neither via Intel Driver & Support Assistant nor via Driver Booster for my Intel® 82865G Graphics Controller to get OpenGL 2+. Regards once more.